# Predicate vs Function PROLOG

Tags: prolog

I am a beginner in PROLOG and attached are the problems i was assigned. I do not know the difference between them, especially the difference between a predicate and a function.. as with some research I understood that a function is a predicate. This is what I've come up with so far:

qr(Num1, Num2, Quotient, Remainder) :- Num1 is 50, Num2 is 3, Quotient is Num1/Num2, Remainder is Num1 mod Num2.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFCah.png

Comment: There is no important distinction calling it a "predikat" instead of a "function" though many Prolog programmers like to champion the unique "Prolog way" . As a pragmatic consideration Prolog provides "functions" same as any other language except Prolog adds capacity for every function to be "true" or "false" independent of it's return values . Another way to think of it is that Prolog steals the return value slot for its own use as a true/false indicator thus to return values in Prolog pass a variable in as an argument slot and use that to return something .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Prolog "function" is not a special kind of syntactic element so I don't think that you have to spend to much time thinking about the distinction "predicate"/"function". You could say "predicate" in both cases.

Here is an example predicate for computing the sum which you can generalise to your case: `mySum(X1, X2, Sum):- Sum is X1 + X2`. You could then call this as follows `?-mySum(1, 2, X)`.

One way of reading the Prolog construct `Head:- Body` is as follows: "To execute Head, first execute Body". In body you can thus have the built-in predicate `write/1` to output to the screen.

Cheers/JC